# Banshee intelligent playlist including subfolders

Tags: banshee, smart

Is it possible to create intelligent/smart playlist of folder "2011" with all it's subfolders?

I've tried to do this, but Banshee 2.2.1 seems not to go deeper for music files than to the specified folder.

Comment: Could you give use the details of the smart playlist? A screenshot of the smart playlist dialog would be great.

Comment: It looks like this: http://imagecdn.maketecheasier.com/2010/12/banshee-smart-playlist.png

There are more options like 'file location starts with/contains..' but it doesn't include subfolders, only the main folder.

Answer (score 2):

"File Location Contains" should do what you want.  Imagine the following scenario:

I have three Radiohead albums, and the songs are stored in the following folders:

```
~/Music/Radiohead/OK Computer/
~/Music/Radiohead/Kid A/
~/Music/Radiohead/In Rainbows/
```

If I create a new smart playlist in Banshee with the criteria `contains Music/Radiodead/`, it will match all three of the folders listed above because they each contain `Music/Radiohead/` in their path.